# The function is not returning in clang

Tags: c, clang, cs50

I am trying to make a program to calculate the area of a rectangle
but the function doesn't return any value

This is the code as in cs50 sandbox

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int calcrectarea(int len,int wid){
    return len*wid;
}

int main(){        
    printf("enter length here:\n");         
    int x; scanf("%d",&x);

    printf("enter width here:\n");
    int y; scanf("%d", &y);

    calcrectarea(x,y);           
}
```

Comment: The function does return a value, but you're not doing anything with it. Try assigning it to a variable or printing it.

Comment: What output do you expect? [Edit] and show an example of input and exepected output. Also read this: [ask]

Comment: `calcrectarea(x,y);` should be `int result = calcrectarea(x,y);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the function returns a value. Maybe you want to see it, so just print the result:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int calcrectarea(int len,int wid){
    return len*wid;
}

int main(){        
    printf("enter length here:\n");         
    int x; scanf("%d",&x);

    printf("enter width here:\n");
    int y; scanf("%d", &y);

    printf("area is: %d", calcrectarea(x,y));           
}
```